# Time Delta of Year Excluding Certain Days

Tags: python, date, datetime, pandas, timedelta

I am making a heat map that has Company Name on the x axis, months on the y-axis, and shaded regions as the number of calls.

I am taking a slice of data from a database for the past year in order to create the heat map. However, this means that if you hover over the current month, say for example today is July 13, you will get the calls of July 1-13 of this year, and the calls of July 13-31 from last year added together. In the current month, I only want to show calls from July 1-13.

```
#This section selects the last year of data
# convert strings to datetimes
df['recvd_dttm'] = pd.to_datetime(df['recvd_dttm'])

#Only retrieve data before now (ignore typos that are future dates)
mask = df['recvd_dttm'] <= datetime.datetime.now()
df = df.loc[mask]
# get first and last datetime for final week of data

range_max = df['recvd_dttm'].max()
range_min = range_max - datetime.timedelta(days=365)

# take slice with final week of data
df = df[(df['recvd_dttm'] >= range_min) & 
               (df['recvd_dttm'] <= range_max)]
```

Comment: `datetime.timedelta(days=365)` will not work for  leap years

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, yes, that is another problem with this approach.

Comment: `- pd.DateOffset(years=1)`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I get this error: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'DateOffset'

Comment: Made a typo and wrote df.DateOffset instead. Thank you, it works now.

Comment: @jenryb did my approach answer your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `pd.tseries.offsets.MonthEnd()` to achieve your goal here.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime as dt

np.random.seed(0)
val = np.random.randn(600)
date_rng = pd.date_range('2014-01-01', periods=600, freq='D')

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(dates=date_rng,col=val))
print(df)

        col      dates
0    1.7641 2014-01-01
1    0.4002 2014-01-02
2    0.9787 2014-01-03
3    2.2409 2014-01-04
4    1.8676 2014-01-05
5   -0.9773 2014-01-06
6    0.9501 2014-01-07
7   -0.1514 2014-01-08
8   -0.1032 2014-01-09
9    0.4106 2014-01-10
..      ...        ...
590  0.5433 2015-08-14
591  0.4390 2015-08-15
592 -0.2195 2015-08-16
593 -1.0840 2015-08-17
594  0.3518 2015-08-18
595  0.3792 2015-08-19
596 -0.4700 2015-08-20
597 -0.2167 2015-08-21
598 -0.9302 2015-08-22
599 -0.1786 2015-08-23

[600 rows x 2 columns]


print(df.dates.dtype)
datetime64[ns]


datetime_now = dt.datetime.now()
datetime_now_month_end = datetime_now + pd.tseries.offsets.MonthEnd(1)

print(datetime_now_month_end)
2015-07-31 03:19:18.292739


datetime_start = datetime_now_month_end - pd.tseries.offsets.DateOffset(years=1)

print(datetime_start)
2014-07-31 03:19:18.292739


print(df[(df.dates > datetime_start) & (df.dates < datetime_now)])

        col      dates
212  0.7863 2014-08-01
213 -0.4664 2014-08-02
214 -0.9444 2014-08-03
215 -0.4100 2014-08-04
216 -0.0170 2014-08-05
217  0.3792 2014-08-06
218  2.2593 2014-08-07
219 -0.0423 2014-08-08
220 -0.9559 2014-08-09
221 -0.3460 2014-08-10
..      ...        ...
550  0.1639 2015-07-05
551  0.0963 2015-07-06
552  0.9425 2015-07-07
553 -0.2676 2015-07-08
554 -0.6780 2015-07-09
555  1.2978 2015-07-10
556 -2.3642 2015-07-11
557  0.0203 2015-07-12
558 -1.3479 2015-07-13
559 -0.7616 2015-07-14

[348 rows x 2 columns]
```

Comment: This actually answers the question... Except it includes the 31st with the Months End, and I want it to start at the 1st of the next month. This can be fixed just by adding another day range_max = datetime.datetime.now() + pd.tseries.offsets.MonthEnd(1) + pd.tseries.offsets.DateOffset(days=1)